# can we initialise char[] array blank in java?

Tags: arrays, char, initialization

Want to use char[] array but can't define the value at init. can i do that like

```
char[] reverse;
```

if i do that `char[] reverse = {}` it will throw an error. later will assign value.

Answer (score 0):

In Java arrays cannot change of dimension. If you want to create an empty `List` for later use you can do as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

// This is an array of Size 0. It cannot be used
char array[] =new char[0];
// List of mutable size
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
list.add('C');
```